# Determine if polynomials are subspaces of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The question is:

> Determine if sets $U$ and $V$ are subspaces of vector space $\ P_3 \ (P_3 = \{a_2x^2 + a_1x +a_0: a_2, a_1, a_0 \in P_3 \}) $, when:
>
> - $U = \{a_2x^2 + a_1x +a_0 \in P_3: a_2x^2 + a_1x +a_0 = 0 \land 2a_2 + a_1 = 0 \}$
> - $V = \{p(x) = a_2x^2 + a_1x +a_0 \in P_3: p(0) < p(1)\}$

I know that $W$ is a subspace of $V$ if:

- $W \neq \emptyset $
- $\forall x, y \in W, x + y \in W $
- $\forall x \in W, \forall \alpha \in \mathbb R, \alpha x \in W $

What I am not sure about are those conditions in sets $U$ and $V$. What is the right approach when solving this type of task?

Comment: The horizontal space between the bullet point and the text and the bold italic style for $U$ and $V$ are unnecessary.  I've [edit]ed them away.  Please [use MathJax for math objects](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/22029/290189) and [plain text font for normal text](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27542/290189).

Comment: Are you sure you've quoted the definition of $U$ correctly? The first of the condition contains $x$ which has no value. Formally it might mean that the entire polynomial must be the zero polynomial, but then the second condition becomes pointless.

Comment: @HenningMakholm The definition of U is exactly the same as in my worksheet.

Comment: I’d bet that there’s a cut-and-paste error and it was meant to read $a_2+a_1+a_0=0$.